# Need for normalization in non-degenerate perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, normalization

I'm currently taking a class in QM and we came across the topic of non-degenerate perturbation theory. Let us for further discussions assume that $H_0$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian with solutions of the form $$H_0\phi_n=\epsilon_n\phi_n,$$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since we are looking at the non-degenerate case we know that $\epsilon_n\neq \epsilon_m$  for all $m\neq n$. Let $H'$ be the perturbation and let 
$$\psi = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lambda^i\psi_i,\hspace{0.5cm} E = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lambda^iE_i.$$
The new problem that we now want to solve is 
$$H\psi = E\psi,$$ 
where $H\equiv H_0+H'$.
We can now show that the following relationship holds $$H_0\psi_i+H'\psi_{i-1} = \sum_{j=0}^iE_j\psi_{i-j},$$ with the convention $\psi_{-1}=0$. For $i=0$ we get $\psi_0=\phi_n$, and for the case $i=1$ we find $$(H_0-E_0)\psi_1=(E_1-H')\psi_0.$$ 
In my lecture notes it now says that any linear combination of $\psi_1$ and $\psi_0$ would solve this equation and we therefore need another condition, which we eventually choose to be $\langle \phi_n\vert\psi_k\rangle =\delta_0^k$, to have a unique solution.

I'm having a hard time seeing the need for such an extra condition. I've tried to look it up but most of the time the normalization is just assumed (for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)), or in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/156722/177167)) to hold anyways and not much of an explanation is given.

---

**TL;DR**: Why do we need such an extra condition and how can I see that?

Comment: I think you've messed up your notation a bit. You state that $H_0\phi_i+H'\phi_{i-1} = \sum_{j=0}^iE_j\phi_{i-j}$, but you define $\phi_n$ as the $n$th eigenstate of $H_0$, which would imply that the corrections to $\phi_0$ depends on $\phi_1$. What you really want is the _first order correction_ to the $n$th eigenstate.

Comment: @HantingZhang thank you very much for pointing this out! Could you maybe take a look at it now and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing a answer rn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my lecture notes it now says that any linear combination of $\psi_1$ and $\psi_0$ would solve this equation [...]

Indeed, if $(H^0-E^0_n)\psi_n^1=(E^1_n-H')\psi_n^0$, then we can see that if $\psi_n^1$ satisfies the equation above, then $\psi_n^1 + k\psi_n^0$ will too:
$$(H_0-E_n^0)(\psi_n^1 + k\psi_n^0) = (H_0-E_n^0)\psi_n^1 + k(H_0-E_n^0)\psi_0$$
$$ = (H_0-E_n^0)\psi_n^1 + k(E_n^0-E_n^0)\psi_n^0 = (H_0-E_n^0)\psi_n^1.$$
We've added nothing to our equation.

Since our *unperturbed* eigenfunctions constitute of complete, orthonormal set, we can write $$\psi_n^1 = \sum_{m} c^{(n)}_m\psi_m^0,$$
where the fancy $(n)$ in $c^{(n)}_m$ in just bookkeeping for which $\psi_n^1$ we're talking about.  Now, from above, we have the freedom to subtract off the $c^{(n)}_n\psi^0_n$ term in the sum, turning it into:
$$\psi_n^1 = \sum_{m \neq n} c^{(n)}_m\psi_m^0.$$ Taking the inner product with $\langle\psi_n^0\vert$ on both sides,

$$\langle\psi_n^0\vert\psi_n^1\rangle = \langle\psi_n^0\vert\sum_{m \neq n} c^{(n)}_m\vert\psi_m^0\rangle = \sum_{m \neq n} c^{(n)}_m\langle\psi_n^0\vert\psi_m^0\rangle = 0.$$

That's how we *get* the normalization.

> Why do we need such an extra condition and how can I see that?

Sometimes, we are interested in the perturbations to the *wavefunction* $\psi_n^1$, for which we can solve for with $$(H^0-E^0_n)\psi_n^1=(E^1_n-H')\psi_n^0.$$
Since $$\psi_n^1 = \sum_{m \neq n} c^{(n)}_m\psi_m^0,$$
the problem reduces to finding the coeifficents $c^{(n)}_m$.
Plugging in $\psi_n^1$, we have
$$\sum_{m \neq n} (E^0_m - E^0_n)c^{(n)}_m\psi_m^0 = (E^1_n-H')\psi_n^0.$$
Then, taking the inner product with $\psi_k^0$,

$$\sum_{m \neq n} (E^0_m - E^0_n)c^{(n)}_m\langle\psi_k^0\vert\psi_m^0\rangle = E^1_n\langle\psi_k^0\vert\psi_n^0\rangle-\langle\psi_k^0\vert H'\vert \psi_n^0\rangle.$$

If $k = n$, then the entire LHS is $0$, and we just get the equation for the first order perturbations to the energy. If $k \neq n$, then 
$$ (E^0_k - E^0_n)c^{(n)}_m = -\langle\psi_k^0\vert H'\vert \psi_n^0\rangle.$$
Hence
$$c^{(n)}_m = \frac{\langle\psi_m^0\vert H'\vert \psi_n^0\rangle}{E^0_n - E^0_m} \rightarrow \psi_n^1 = \sum_{m \neq n} \frac{\langle\psi_m^0\vert H'\vert \psi_n^0\rangle}{E^0_n - E^0_m}\psi^0_m.$$

Notice that the demonimator is *safe*, because we pulled out the $n = m$ term right from the beginning. By choosing the extra condition, we can avoid some serious trouble.

- Note: this is only for *non-degenerate perturbation theory*.